# Добавление в два списка

Tags: javascript

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', handle);

function handle() {

  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  var textElem = input.value;

  var first = document.getElementById('first');
  var second = document.getElementById('second');

  var elem = document.createElement('li');
  elem.innerHTML = textElem;

  first.appendChild(elem);
  second.appendChild(elem);

};
```

```css
body { width: 250px; }
#first { float: left; color: red; }
#second { float: right; color: green; }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter text">
<button id="button">Submit</button>  
<ul id="first"></ul>
<ul id="second"></ul>
```

Код из примера добавляет элемент в список только последний `appendChild`, как сделать, чтоб добавлялось в два списка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените последнюю строчку в функции на

```
second.appendChild(elem.cloneNode(true));
```